# How to add item which contains timer function using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically add item which contains a timer.For now, it only update the timer value when added new item.
How to update the timer value of each item per second?

**HTML**

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in items">
       ID:<label>{{item.id}}</label> </br>
       time:{{item.time}} 
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    function random(min,max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    }
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        var item = {};
        item.id = random(0,10);
        item.created = new Date();
        item.timer =  setInterval(function() {
                        var cur = new Date();
                        item.time = (cur.getTime() - item.created);
                      },1000); 
        $scope.items.push(item);        
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9DAW9/)

Comment: Or you can use Angular provided `$timeout` to get rid of `$scope.$apply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the body of timer with `$scope.$apply` to notify AngularJS that model is changed and it should update the view:

```
item.timer =  setInterval(function() {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
       var cur = new Date();
       item.time = (cur.getTime() - item.created);
   });
},1000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9DAW9/1/)